# How to display only subdomain and not IP address in address bar

Tags: subdomain, nginx, amazon-aws, amazon-ec2, route53

I have a nodejs application running on EC2 instance.
The nodejs application is running on port 7000, and I'm using nginx to listen to port 80 and forward any request to that port (so if someone type: `http://1.23.45.6/get_data` it's like he types: `http://1.23.45.6:7000/get_data`).
This part is good, but now I want to use a subdomain to get to that nodejs application.

So when people type in the address bar: **fofo.example.com** they will be my nodejs application.

I create an A record for that subdomain to point to my IP address, but for some reason when I type my subdomain in the address bar it changes and revealed the IP address I wanted to hide...

What I did wrong or what do I need to change in order to show only my subdomain and don't reveal the IP address.

Comment: You'll have to configure nginx to serve up your site under your domain name. Use the server_name directive https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: I agree with Maximilian. You'll have to post your Nginx configuration for this site so we can help you figure out what's wrong with it.